# why can't I install flake8 by pip?

Tags: pip, flake8

I did like this

```
pip install flake8
```

then, terminal says that it has already installed and it is in 
`.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.1.0/lib/python3.4/site-packages.` But,I did like this

```
which flake8
```

then, terminal says nothing. Why? I couldn't install that ?

Comment: Your `PATH` environment variable is probably not set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29 What is the result of? echo $PATH Have you modified any of your init files (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile` or any similar) since you installed anaconda? What is the result of? which python which pip which conda

Comment: Thanks ! Please read below comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `pip` is using your pyenv installed version of python from anaconda. With that in mind, you should ensure that `python` points to that as well and do `python -m flake8`. That will let you run flake8.

Flake8 does not control where it's executable is installed to, but as long as you use the same `python` as is being used by `pip`, then you will still be able to run it.

Comment: It sounds strange, but I `which` again , then the terminal returned `/Users/myusername/.pyenv/shims/flake8`. Anyway, Thank you for answering.(But I wonder why `which` returned nothing.)

Comment: Depending no your shell, you may have a cache of what commands are found in your `$PATH`. To bust/regenerate that cache, you can do `rehash` so you don't have to restart your terminal. Cheers!